# Comass norm: why do we take simple vectors?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms, geometric-measure-theory

I am studying geometric measure theory and there's a thing that always bothers me when I think about it: the definition of comass norm. It's all nice and clear, don't get me wrong: given a $m$-covector $\xi$ we define its comass norm to be

\begin{equation}
||\xi||^* = \sup_{|v| =1, \text{ simple}} |\langle \xi ,v \rangle |
\end{equation}

where $v$ is a $m$-vector and $|\cdot |$ is the standard euclidean norm, i.e. if $v=v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_m$, then $|v|= \sqrt{det (\langle v_i , v_j \rangle })$. Then you define the mass norm for $m$-vectors as the dual of $|| \cdot ||^*$, so far so good. But why did someone think of imposing the fact that $v$ must be simple? Now, if I remember correctly  in general you can associate $m$-vectors with an oriented $m$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a canonical way only if $v$ is simple, but still I cannot see why to bother or why someone thought it was necessary to add the "simple" condition to the definition.

Comment: You’re right, I’ve done it, but the comass norm was already defined

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, I should have seen it...

Comment: Precisely because we want to look at only (normalized) oriented $m$-planes (e.g., those tangent to a submanifold or something more general). I don't understand your phrase "in a canonical way": How does a non-simple $m$-vector correspond to an oriented $m$-plane?

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah but why do we only want to look at them? What's the reasoning that leads one to such constriction? I am talking about a geometric measure theory point of view, maybe in other fields this is much more natural (actually, maybe it's really natural in gmt, too, just that I don't see it). As for how to associate a non simple vector to a m-plane in a non canonical way: I am not sure. If I am not mistaken, it was something the teacher mentioned, but it was just an observation, and I haven't the notes at teh moment. As soon as I can check, I'll try to articulate on this

Answer (score 1):

This was confusing to me when learning geometric measure theory, so even though the question is old, let me give an answer for posterity.

We are ultimately interested in the comass of a differential $k$-form $\varphi$ on a Riemannian manifold $M$, which is given by
$$\|\varphi\|^* := \sup_{x \in M} \|\varphi(x)\|^*,$$
or in other words it is the supremum of the comasses of the $k$-vectors $\varphi$. This quantity is
$$\|\varphi\|^* = \sup \left[\frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}(\Sigma)} \int_\Sigma \varphi\right]$$
where the supremum ranges over all oriented $k$-dimensional submanifolds $\Sigma \subset M$ of $k$-dimensional volume at most $1$. You can see this by observing that at the infinitesimal level, integrating $\varphi$ along $\Sigma$ is just pairing $\varphi(x)$ with $\beta_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \beta_k$ where $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_k$ is an orthonormal basis for the tangent space $T_x \Sigma$, and then summing this pairing $\langle \varphi, \beta_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \beta_k\rangle$ over all $x$.

This is exactly where the assumption that the test $k$-vectors in the definition of the comass are simple comes from: $\beta_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \beta_k$ is simple, essentially because $\Sigma$ has a well-defined tangent space. If we didn't make this assumption, we would not just be testing against submanifolds, but more complicated chains (such as $\{x = y = 0\} + \{z = w = 0\}$ in $\mathbb R^4$), but this isn't as useful.

One of the main goals of this "testing against submanifolds" definition is to define the word "calibration". A *calibration* is a $k$-form $\varphi$ such that $d\varphi = 0$ and $\|\varphi\|^* = 1$. It turns out that lots of natural $k$-forms in geometry are calibrations, most prominently $\varphi = \omega^p/p!$ where $\omega$ is the natural $2$-form on a Kaehler manifold and $k = 2p$. A submanifold $\Sigma$ is said to be $\varphi$-*calibrated* if it attains the supremum, that is,
$$\int_\Sigma \varphi = \mathrm{vol}(\Sigma).$$
The *fundamental theorem of calibrated geometry*, which is just a rephrasing of Stokes' theorem, says that a $\varphi$-calibrated manifold is volume-minimizing in its homology class (relative to its boundary). Thus the Wirtinger inequality says that complex submanifolds of a Kaehler manifold are volume-minimizing.

Comment: It's always nice to give more publicity to Harvey and Lawson's theory of calibrations :)